# Проверка на input type="text"

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть `input type="text"` и `button`. Нужно сделать проверку: если в `input type="text"` введено более одного символа, то кнопка активна, если менее одного, то - неактивна.

```
<input type="text" id="text1">
<button id="btn"></button>
```